# Schneider's theorem about the transcendence of values of the $j$-function

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, transcendental-numbers

It is known that the [$j$-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant) takes algebraic values when evaluated at imaginary quadratic integers. This is a result that was proved by Schneider in 1937 apparently. To be precise, [Schneider proved](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant#Transcendence_properties) that

> > If $z \in \mathbb{H} = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mid \Im{(z)} > 0  \}$ and $j(z)$ is an algebraic integer. Then $z$ is algebraic if and only if $z$ is an imaginary quadratic integer.

I would really appreciate if someone can provide me some nice reference(s) where this result is proved.

Thank you very much for any help.